# How can I optimize my ajax code so that the browser does not freeze?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script that makes multiple ajax calls that causes my browser to freeze.

I tried to add a loader through ajaxStart, but that does not prevent all ajax calls from being multiple.

I just want to help me optimize my code so that the browser does not freeze, I don't know much about programming, I would appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **async:true**
$.ajax in jQuery is set to asynchronous (async) to true default.While Asynchronous (async:true) request, the process is handled independently and is not dependent on following processes. So processing asynchronously avoids the delay response from the server.

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/product_info.php",
    data: {id: "" + productId},
    dataType: "html"
});
```